# Unable to display subscript text in textView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview, subscript

I'm quite new to Android and I'm trying to display some chemical formulas in a textView which is contained in a customListView.
I'm fetching all datas from xml parsing, then I wish to display the formula, such as C₉H₈O₄.
But I can see only 1-4 digits.

I'm converting from "normal" to "subscript" in this way

```
str = str.replaceAll("0", "\u2080");
str = str.replaceAll("1", "\u2081");
str = str.replaceAll("2", "\u2082");
str = str.replaceAll("3", "\u2083");
str = str.replaceAll("4", "\u2084");
str = str.replaceAll("5", "\u2085");
str = str.replaceAll("6", "\u2086");
str = str.replaceAll("7", "\u2087");
str = str.replaceAll("8", "\u2088");
str = str.replaceAll("9", "\u2089");
```

str contains the formula fetched from the xml file.

The strange behavior is that I can see in the Logcat the formula as it should be.

I also tried with customs fonts but nothing.

Here are two results:
the first is with normal font, the second with a custom one

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jyk64p700up14db/cella.jpg
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ab9h1b45j2hrods/Schermata%2003-2456370%20alle%2022.05.45.png

Over the web I can read as a solution using something like

setText(Html.fromHtml("X`<sub>2</sub>`"));

but I really don't know how to use it in my case.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It will not be easy trying to solv that problem with `Html.fromHtml("X<sub>2</sub>")`
you need a lib that can help you to achieve that

(JEuclid is a complete MathML rendering solution, consisting of:) `http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/`

Look at the example and you'll get a way to resolve your issue

Other alternatives for rendering math expressions with TeX:

```
http://jmathtex.sourceforge.net/
http://sourceforge.net/projects/snuggletex/
http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem: It was a font issue. 
I just used Calibri and It works!